# How to render variable in string in <Text> JSX tag in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

How to enable template string in React Native? My code doesn't work:

```js
<Text>{`My name is ${name}`}</Text>
```

Comment: I found the cause of a bug was coming from another part, not in Text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need of adding template strings inside a `<Text>` component for adding strings in `react-native`. You can just use simple text and for variables, you can wrap it with curly braces.

```
<Text>My name is {name}</Text>
```